# Error: TypeError: $(…).dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

i am trying to load a dialog box using jquery.but the problem is that when i click on a link to open the dialog box it did'nt open.also i get an error as" $("#dv").dialog is not a function "
this is my code

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function adminl(){
        $("#uname").val("");
        $("#uemail").val("");
        $("#uphone").val("");
        $("#umessage").val("");
        $('#contact_form_errorloc').html("");
        $('#dv').dialog({
            modal:true,
            title:"Contact Us",
            width:390,
            height:570,
            });
    }

<div id="dv" style="display:none">

<style>
label,a, body 
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px; 
}
.err
{
    font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px;
    color: red;
}
</style>    


<div id='contact_form_errorloc' class="err"></div>
<form  name="contact_form" id="contact_form" > 




<p>
<label for='name'>Name: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" size=43 />
</p>
<p>
<label for='email'>Email: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="uemail" id="uemail" size=43 />
</p>
<p>
<label for='phone'>Phone Number: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="uphone" id="uphone" size=43 />
</p>
<p>
<label for='message'>Comments/Questions:</label> <br>
<textarea name="umessage" id="umessage" rows=8 cols=40></textarea>
</p>
<p style="width:2px; margin-top:10px;">
<?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "6Lf948kSAAAAADGf542VNVyURY_WtsyAk7LbUvtD"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
</p>
<input type="button" class="submit_ad_button" style="border:0; margin-bottom:10px;margin-left: 0; float:left;" value="Send" onClick="form_submit()"/>
</form>
</div>
<a onclick="adminl(event)">contact us</a>
```

Comment: Make sure all your js files are getting loaded to the page .

Comment: remove `,` from `height:570,`

Comment: There are so many basic errors in the markup and javascript that nothing will work. I pasted your code to my local server, reformatted it so I could read it, added several HTML tags that were missing, moved the script tags around, opened the page in a browser, clicked the `contact us` link, and a dialog popped up.

Comment: [Error: TypeError: $(…).dialog is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26016562/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call **.dialog("open")** in order to make it visible.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Comment: `$("#dialog").dialog();` is enough to display a basic dialog with jQueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

Is the dialog script actually in the custom jQuery UI script that you are loading? If there were errors in the properties you are passing to `dialog()` then I wouldn't expect to see your error of "('#').dialog is not a function".