# TypeError dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I need help with this javascript code. I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
```

Code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('#tdog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     width: 200,
     modal: true,
  });
});
</script>

<div id="tdog"></div>
```

I included the jquery import in the header. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include jQuery UI or what ever library you are using? There is no dialog in jQuery core.

Comment: It says exactly what is wrong...It simply means that the method is not available. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: I did include it like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok, when do you call the function after or before the included file? And are you sure the file is found?

Comment: I call it after the included file. I'm pretty sure it is found. When I check the network tab in Chrome, I see it that it was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The script is running before the div has been loaded on the page, thus it is unavailable, add the ready function to ensure it is loaded first.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#tdog').dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       width: 200,
       modal: true,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you forgot to include jquery UI.
See this answer for reference: 
[Error: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016562/error-typeerror-dialog-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the ui and also the styles before starting the script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function () {
$('#tdog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     width: 200,
     modal: true,
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, I had a minified version of all the js files in /public/js/app.js being included in app.blade.php (main template page). I commented out the inclusion of app.js and the error went away, presumably because of the 'included twice' points made above.