# Closing an HTML form in a jQuery modal with the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have inherited the following HTML form in a jQuery modal:

```
<div id = "openModal" class = "modalDialog">
<div>
<a href = "#close" title = "close" class = "close">X</a>
<form id = "write_us_form" action="" method = "post">
    <div class = "form_container">
        <label class = "form_label">Name</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form_textfield" name = "f_name"><br>
        <label class = "form_label">E-mail</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form_textfield" name = "f_email"><br>
        <label class = "form_label">Subject</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form_textfield" name = "f_subject"><br>
        <label class = "form_label">Message</label>
        <textarea class = "form_textarea" name = "f_message" rows = "5"></textarea>
        <input type = "submit" class = "form_submit_button" value = "Send message">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

When I click the submit button, the following jQuery script runs, apparently to not refresh the page and run the send_form.php file to send an email:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#write_us_form').on('submit', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault (); // prevent page reload
        $.ajax (
        {
            type : 'POST', // hide URL
            url : 'send_form.php', // form validation file
            data : $('#write_us_form').serialize (),
            success : function (data)
            {
                $('#openModal').dialog('close');
                alert ('Thank you for contacting us!');
            }
            });
        });
    });
```

The code does not do two things:
1. Close the modal. I already added the dialog('close') part, but it does not have any effect.
2. If I close the modal with the close button, and then click the proper button on the website that displays the modal, the form still has the previous contents in it.

The php part works, the proper email is sent, I'm just trying to find a way to close the modal and possibly refresh the form when it is opened again.

Thanks for any bit of help!

Comment: While I'm not familiar enough with jQuery modals (I wrote my own modal system with - in my personal opinion - better features), but for the form I can definitely suggest this: `$("#write_us_form")[0].reset();` - resets the form to its default values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Niet, item #2 solved!

Comment: You are using jQuery UI? Do you see the alert?

Comment: As the stuff is inherited, judging by the script includes in the head section, jQuery UI is not included. And no, the alert does not show up either.

Comment: So what is the `dialog` plug-in? Add an error handler to your Ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Your dialog box might not be closing if your ajax call is not successful.  If your 'Thank you for contacting us' alert is being executed and your modal is still not closing, it could be an issue with your syntax.  It could be the case, that your modal is a bootstrap modal in which case the syntax would be different.  You would want to `hide` the modal.

In the case of the form contents, you want to `reset` the form in the success block.  See your modified code below:

```
$('#write_us_form').on('submit', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault (); // prevent page reload
        $.ajax (
        {
            type : 'POST', // hide URL
            url : 'send_form.php', // form validation file
            data : $('#write_us_form').serialize (),
            success : function (data)
            {
                $('#openModal').modal('hide');
                $("#write_us_form").trigger("reset");
                alert ('Thank you for contacting us!');
            }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$('#openModal').modal('hide');`

Comment: Chishaku, unfortunately it still does not close. It does not seem to get past the modal hide part, as the form does not reset and the alert does not show up either.

Comment: @epascarello I was making assumptions about the use of bootstrap.  I modified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @hPi The issue is not related to the modal then.  Your ajax call is not returning a success status code so all the code in the success block is not executing.  You need to inspect the response and status code of your `send_form.php` route to identify the error.

Comment: Strangely, if I take out the modal hide part and leave the trigger reset and the alert only, then the fields reset and the alert shows up. Only the modal does not close. So the success part runs...

Comment: @hPi Now what happens if you change it from `.modal('hide')` to `.dialog('close')`?

Comment: @chishaku Nothing. Form does not reset and the alert does not show up, but the php script runs fine.

Comment: Open the console in your browser developer tools.  Then click submit and see what error is showing.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
$.ajax.success @ index.html:73
fire @ jquery-latest.js:3
self.fireWith @ jquery-latest.js:3done @ jquery-latest.js:7callback @ jquery-latest.js:7

Comment: Line 73 is the modal close / hide line.

Comment: Check your script imports.  Are you importing `jquery-ui`?  You should see something like this in your html head: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: No, only jquery was used. I added jQuery UI, and now the error reads: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'" Also tried changing to hide, same error message. Sorry if I seem a bit lost, I am, just trying to figure out someone else's code...

Comment: @hPi No worries, that's progress.  Now you need to make sure to initialize the dialog box.  See this answer for more details.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016562/error-typeerror-dialog-is-not-a-function

Comment: OK, added the init section according to the link, but when I click the button, the modal does not even appear now :) I checked spelling, checked with dev tools, no errors... no modal.

Comment: @hPi To be honest, I'm not intimately familiar with jquery-ui.  I would test a 'hello world' example of the modal separate from the code you're inheriting and then modify accordingly.   The trouble with inheriting code is that there could be many potential issues.  In those cases, I try to strip down to the bare bones and then add back what is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, will try to do that... just tried avoiding it :) Thanks for you help and patience, really appreciate it!