# Dialog gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, typeerror

I'm simply trying to open a JQ dialog and I get a JS TypeError (not a function).
Here's the div:

```
<div id="change_dialog" style="display:none">
        Change the number of attendees<br /> for <span id="name_to_change">    </span>?
        <select id="change_select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        </select></p>
       <input type="button" id="change_qty_button"  value="Change" /> &nbsp;<input type="button" id="change_abort" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
$('#change_button').click(function(){
    $(".res_button").each(function(){   
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            $id = $(this).val();
            change_name=$("#"+$id).val();
        }
    });
    $('#name_to_change').html(change_name);
    $('#change_dialog').dialog('open'); 
    $('.button_class').hide();
    return false;
}); 

$('#change_dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false,
    minWidth: 180,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    title: "Attendee Quantity Change",
    show:{ effect: "fold", duration: 1000 },
    hide:{ effect: "fold", duration: 1000 }
});
```

Here's the error line:

> TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

The line to which the error points is:  `$('#change_dialog').dialog({`

I see nothing wrong, anywhere.  I've commented various lines up the kazoo to try to isolate the error.  Even when the function is present but empty, I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you include jQuery UI, the `dialog()` is not part of jQuery

Comment: ^ this. The error is telling you everything you need to know. You're not including jQuery UI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016562/error-typeerror-dialog-is-not-a-function)

Comment: This is it!!  Somehow this little section got commented out:  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you'll need to include the jQuery UI library, its hosted at https://code.jquery.com/ui/.  Additionally, you've got a small error in your javascript that'll give you an undefined variable error.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#change_button').click(function(){
      var change_name; //if not included, is undefined at line 10
      $(".res_button").each(function(){   
          if ($(this).prop('checked')){
              $id = $(this).val();
              change_name = $("#"+$id).val();
          }
      });
      $('#name_to_change').html(change_name);  //this was undefined
      $('#change_dialog').dialog('open'); 
      $('.button_class').hide();
      return false;
  });
```

You can see it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2pkzsxun/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: The two "undefined" variables are defined at the top of the script - sorry I left them out of the question.  Also, the jQuery UI library is included at the top of the page.  I don't see why document.ready should be necessary.  This is one of those cases where "it always worked" but suddenly, without any changes, stopped working.  Just for the fun of it, however, I put the function into a document.ready function already on the page.  No cigar.  Same error.

Comment: As it turns out, on additional investigation, the jquery ui was commented out  -  who knows how !  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>