# jquery ui dialog wont open again

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I am having problems with jquery dialog. I have multiple divs acting as buttons, and want to open the dialog with different results, depending on the div clicked. This all works, but when I press a second button, I get the error message "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function".

If I delete the ajax call, it works fine, so I guess that I have to "delete" or "close" something to get subsequent button clicks to work.

The alert() fires both times, but nothing happens after that.

In the simplified code, I have REMMED the ajax call, so it will work, but of course with blank dialogs.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='large-3 columns'>
        <div class='floatleft changepriority' id='1026' style='padding:6px;'>[1026] 0 : </div>
        <div class='floatleft changepriority' id='715' style='padding:6px;'>[715] 1000 : </div>
        <!-- Various more "buttons" -->
    </div>
</div>

<script src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/what-input/what-input.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js'></script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $(document).foundation();

        $( '#changetasklist' ).dialog({

            modal: true,
            autoResize:true,

/*
            open: function () {
                $(this).load('/ajax/changetasklist.php?tl=' + $('#changetasklist').data('tasklist'));
            },
*/
            position: { my: 'center top', at: 'center top+20', of: window },
            width:700,
            title: 'Update Task Heading',
            autoOpen: false, // makes #box hidden when the page starts
            closeOnEscape: true, // closes when ESC is pressed, as well as the [x] top right.
        });

        $( '.changepriority' ).click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
            $( '#changetasklist' ).data('tasklist', this['id']);
            $( '#changetasklist' ).dialog( 'open' );  // open the box
        });

    });
    </script>

<div id='changetasklist'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try referencing the element directly instead of `this` my guess is it isn't what you expect `$("#changetasklist").load(...)`

Comment: If you put a break on the ajax call do you get there the second time.  Is that where the code fails?

Comment: @steve sorry, not clear what you are suggesting that I do withh the "this". 

I only see one this, that is this['id'], which gets the id of the clicked element, id='1026' or id='715'.  and there is no load() in my code. 

Can you clarify, please?

Comment: @steve DUH - yes, I see what you mean now... will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be perhaps related with including a non-updated jQuery UI library. I've just tried with jQuery UI CDN's and didn't have that "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function" problem. Check out this answer: [Error: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016562/error-typeerror-dialog-is-not-a-function)

Also, I think it would be good if you add the content of changetasklist.php because that error occurs when you are making the Ajax call.

Comment: I will simplify changetasklist.php to simplify. I find that this is always the best way to move forward. But whatever click I choose for the first dialog works fine, it's the subsequent clicks that fail.

I will check the library, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It *was* changelist.php that was causing the issue.  I changed it to just echo "hello world", and multiple clicks worked.

So I looked into it further, and found a line
<script src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'></script>

When I removed that line (don't know why it was there!) everything worked. Now all I have to do is figure out why it was there - there is more to do on that file. Thanks for your suggestion