# Adding custom jQuery (modal popup) to wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I made a custom jQuery modal/pop-up and want to add it to my wordpress website.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialogForm">
  <form id="myform" method="post">
    <br><br><br>
    <p id=title name=title><b>VERLOF</b></p>
    <br><br>
    <p id=eerste name=eerste>We zijn gesloten op <b>5 mei.</b></p>
    <p id=tweede name=tweede>Voor dringende interventies, gelieve te <u>mailen <br>of een bericht in te spreken</u>.</p><br>
    <br/>
    <a href="#"><button id=contact name=contact type="submit">Contacteer ons</button></a>
    <button id=close name=close type="submit">Sluiten</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#dialogForm").dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 730,
    height: 490,
    title: "VERLOF",
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 800
    }
  });

  $("#dialogForm").dialog("open");

  $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();

  $('#close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialogForm').dialog('close');
  });
});
```

Code sample:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr13wo8p/)

I found a lot of different ways but none of them seem to work...
Can somebody point my in the right direction please?

Pop-up should be shown on loading of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript:**

1. Save your JavaScript as a `.js` file, such as `my-dialog.js`
2. Put it in your active theme's `/js/` folder (or create it if it doesn't exist)

**CSS:** You have two options:

1. Save it similarly to your JavaScript file above (but put it in a `/css/` folder and name it `my-dialog.css`.
2. Paste your CSS into the **Appearance** > **Customizer** > **Additional CSS** section of your website.

**Loading Those Files**:

Enqueue it in your `functions.php` file with the below code, also read up on [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_scripts/) while you're at it

```
function boeckske_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-dialog', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/my-dialog.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    // If you saved your CSS as a file instead of using the Customizer:
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-dialog', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/my-dialog.css', array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'boeckske_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Now that your JavaScript and Styles are in the site, you need to put the HTML in there, how you do so may vary. The most "broad spectrum" way would be to put it in the footer of your site via `functions.php` like so:

```
function boeckske_dialog_html(){ ?>
    <!-- Paste your Dialog HTML here -->
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'boeckske_dialog_html' );
```

That will get you started. If you only want it on the home page you'll need to wrap the enqueues and/or the HTML with [`is_front_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) or [`is_home()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) - or if you only want it displayed once you'll have to set cookies or something along those lines, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Since it's appearing underneath your site, you should consider wrapping it in another element and adding some CSS to that element, like so:

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-container">
    <div id="dialogForm">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dialog-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

You may have to experiment with it a little bit, but the idea is to make it positioned independently of the rest of the site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
So I did everything what you said, but have a few questions as it is not working as I want it too.

1) the wrap for the home page, like this? is_home(<!-- Paste your Dialog HTML here -->) or something else?

2) it loads everything correctly but the popup/dialog is shown below my page in my footer. It's not popping up. I want it to show when the website is loaded and in front the dialog and in the back the website until the visitor clicks one of the buttons. Do I need to change or add something to the code?

Comment: 1) You may want to read up on the basics of PHP. `is_home()` returns a boolean value so you would use it in an "if" statement: `if( is_home() ){ ?> <!-- Dialog Here-- > <?php } ?>`. 2) You'll need to add some CSS and/or HTML to your dialog. I've updated the answer since it will be easier to see there.

Comment: Ok got it to show how I want to but still have some issues with jQuery. If I delete the code inside the popup.js or add new code, looks like it doesn't  effect anything. I want to close the dialog with the 2nd button but its not doing it now. You have any idea why?

Comment: Well you have `<button id=close name=close…` but it should be `<button id="close" name="close"…` with quotes around the value. If that doesn't work, you may need to add `$('#dialog-container').remove();` underneath `$('#dialogForm').dialog('close');`

Comment: Nope, still not working. I read something that 'get_stylesheet_directory_uri()' needs to change 'get_template_directory_uri()' but also not a solution. Seems my js script is not being detected or linked with the html for some reason.

Comment: Getting this error in my console: TypeError: jQuery(...).dialog is not a function[Meer info]

Comment: ok got it to work! thanks to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016562/error-typeerror-dialog-is-not-a-function