# Error in console after upgrading jQuery to v.3.3.1 and jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm running the following issue: After upgrading to latest jQuery version (3.3.1) and jQueryUI v.1.12.1.

I'm getting the following error:

```
VM133:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:14
    at m (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at Re (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at w.fn.init.append (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at w.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at z (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at w.fn.init.html (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.3.8-dev:2)
```

[image]

The error is affecting my dropdown language menu and displays when a specific language is initialized.

Can you please help me on that, any instructions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016562/error-typeerror-dialog-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Did you check the duplicate suggestion above? If JqueryUI reference is not missing (or pointing to the old version), could you post some sample code of what you are trying to do? So not just the error?

Comment: It sounds like your not referencing the jQuery UI js file.